# setprecision and floating point

Tags: c++, floating-point-precision

Running the following code I expect to receive such an output:

```
Desired output:
Car     Hours    Charge
1        1.5      2.00
2        4.0      2.50
3       24.0     10.00
```

But the results comes out as follows:

```
Actual output:
Car     Hours    Charge
1        2       2
2        4       2.5 
3    2e+01      10
```

Any suggestions that can guide me to use the correct ***floating point*** comparison and using ***setprecision*** correctly is welcome.

```
int main()
{
    double hour[3];
    double charge[3];

    double sum_hour = 0;
    double sum_charge = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    {
        cout<<"Enter the hours for car No. "<<i<<": ";
        cin>>hour [i];

        if (hour [i] <= 3)
            {charge [i] = 2.00;}
        if (hour [i] > 3 && hour [i] < 24)
            {charge [i] = (2.00 + (ceil(hour [i] -3))*0.5);}
        if (hour [i] == 24)
            {charge [i] = 10.00;}

        sum_hour  = sum_hour + hour [i];
        sum_charge = sum_charge + charge [i];
    }

    cout<<"Car"<<setw(10)<<"Hours"<<setw(10)<<"Charge"<<endl;

    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    {
        cout<<i+1<<setw(10)<<setprecision(1)<<hour[i]<<setw(10)<<setprecision(2)<<charge[i]<<endl;
    }
    cout<<"TOTAL"<<setw(6)<<sum_hour<<setw(10)<<sum_charge<<endl;

}
```

Comment: I ran the code in codeblocks. I am just learning the adjustment of floating points and setprecision

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[`std::setprecision`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/setprecision) by default sets the total number of significant digits that are shown (ie. including the ones before the decimal point).

To set the number of digits shown after the decimal point, use [`std::fixed`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/fixed) :

```
std::cout << std::fixed << std::setprecision(2) << 24.0;
```

will display :

```
24.00
```

Comment: How can i back form fixed to standard output?

Comment: @user3895596 : you can use [`std::defaultfloat`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/fixed), to go back to the default floating point formatting.

Answer (score 1):

You need function `fixed` to make cout write digits when it got only '0'.

So use it like this:

```
cout << fixed;
cout<<i+1<<setw(10)<<setprecision(1)<<hour[i]<<setw(10)<<setprecision(2)<<charge[i]<<endl;
```